# Permissão de DROP de tabelas em bancos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ao executar o comando (T-SQL) de DROP abaixo no SQL server é exibido a seguinte mensagem:

> Cannot drop the table '[dbo].[TABELA]', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

**Comando**

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE [?]'
```

Entretanto ao executar outro comando T-SQL ou um DROP Table básico a mensagem de erro acima não é exibida, sendo o comando executado corretamente.

```
DROP TABLE TABELA
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'
```

Ambos os comandos acima funcionam, qual o motivo do `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE [?]'` necessitar de uma permissão? e como dar esta permissão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom o comando `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable` é uma procedure não documentada do SqlServer.
Ela é muito boa quando você se deparar com uma atividade, em que você necessite executar um comando em todas as tabelas. Essa procedure executa atividades em loop através das tabelas.

Existe a variação deste comando para o banco de dados no qual seria o `sp_MSforeachdb`.

O **nível de permissão** que a mesma necessita primeiro obviamente o acesso ao banco de dados e a de permissão para criar stored procedures, por ter a possibilidade de manipular diversas tabelas, sem necessariamente ter conhecimento delas. Caso fosse executado um comando para alterar ou remover uma tupla de uma tabela e fosse executado este comando todas as tabelas que possuíssem uma tupla com este mesmo nome seriam afetadas.

Este [artigo](https://www.tiagoneves.net/blog/procedures-nao-documentadas-sp_msforeachdb-e-sp_msforeachtable/) explica muito bem o seu funcionamento.